# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Decrypt(System.String, System.String)' method

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, encryption, ienumerable

I am trying to display email in `combobox` by filtering using email. My problem is that my data is encrypted in the users table.

When I am trying to decrypt it it giving this error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Decrypt(System.String, System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression

How can I solve this error?

**Here is my Lookup class**

```
    public class Lookup
    {
        public long boundvalue { get; set; }
        public string boundtext { get; set; }
    }
```

**Here is my code to filter**

```
    public IEnumerable<Lookup> getUser(string fText)
            {
                var ret = new List<Lookup>
                              {
                                  new Lookup
                                      {
                                          boundvalue = 0,
                                          boundtext = ""
                                      }
                              };
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fText))
                {
                    ret.AddRange(_entities.Users.Where(x =>EncDec.Decrypt(x.UserVar01.Trim().Replace("_",string.Empty), 
                    Enums.EncDecSecKeyToString(Enums.EncDecSecKey.Email)).Contains(fText.Trim()))
                                 .Select(select => new Lookup
                                 {
                                     boundvalue = select.UserID,
                                     boundtext = EncDec.Decrypt(select.UserVar01.Trim().Replace("_", string.Empty),
                                     Enums.EncDecSecKeyToString(Enums.EncDecSecKey.Email)),
                                 }));

                }
                return ret;
            }
```

Comment: Haven't used `String.Encrypt` and `String.Decrypt`. But what about *encrypting* `fText` before query, instead of *decrypting* `x.UserVar01`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to get a solution it was just a little problem. 
I was suppose to include `ToList()`

```
ret.AddRange(_entities.Users.ToList().Where(x =>EncDec.Decrypt(x.UserVar01.Trim().Replace("_",string.Empty), 
                    Enums.EncDecSecKeyToString(Enums.EncDecSecKey.Email)).Contains(fText.Trim()))
                                 .Select(select => new Lookup
                                 {
                                     boundvalue = select.UserID,
                                     boundtext = EncDec.Decrypt(select.UserVar01.Trim().Replace("_", string.Empty),
                                     Enums.EncDecSecKeyToString(Enums.EncDecSecKey.Email)),
                                 }));
```

Now it working.

Comment: Please be aware that you are materializing the **complete contents** of the table Users. You should only do this if the amount of rows is small. An optimization you can do is to select just the columns you need.

Answer (score 2):

Remember a Linq to Entities query at the end is translated to sql notation but what the error is saying is `System.String Decrypt` is not supported at the time to do that translation. That's why I'm afraid you can't apply the filter in the server side, you will need to do it in memory. To do that use `AsEnumerable` extension method to make the switch to Linq to Objects

```
   ret.AddRange(_entities.Users.AsEnumerable().Where(x =>EncDec.Decrypt(x.UserVar01.Trim().Replace("_",string.Empty), 
                Enums.EncDecSecKeyToString(Enums.EncDecSecKey.Email)).Contains(fText.Trim()))
                             .Select(select => new Lookup
                             {
                                 boundvalue = select.UserID,
                                 boundtext = EncDec.Decrypt(select.UserVar01.Trim().Replace("_", string.Empty),
                                 Enums.EncDecSecKeyToString(Enums.EncDecSecKey.Email)),
                             }));
```

Comment: Would strongly recommend adding some filtering outside the encrypted content so you don't have to pull all of the records back as written. However this is right based on the posted filtering, so no knock on the answer, just FYI OP you should add something so you can filter without decrypting first.